# Django Quill Editor Display Saved Field

Tags: python, html, django, quill

It's probably really simple, but can't figure out how to do that...

I have one really simple model:

```
from django.db import models
from django_quill.fields import QuillField

class Race(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = QuillField()
```

In admin.py

```
from races.models import Race

@admin.register(Race)
class RaceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

So, thru the admin panel, I can use Quill to write text with HTML and add image. Great !

It is saved in the database in Quill delta format.

Now, if I want to display that description field in a template, as html... How Am I suppose to do?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 5):

The html of the description field can be accessed like this (try in django shell):

```
Race.objects.all()[0].html
```

You can for example render all races in an html with the code below.
Note you need to use the 'safe' argument in jinja to have the variable interpreted as html code instead of text.

In the views.py:

```
def show_races(request):
    races_all = Race.objects.all()
    return render(request, "races.html", {"races_all": races_all})
```

In your races.html:

```
{% for race in races_all %}
  <h1> {{ race.name }} </h1>
  {{ race.description.html|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your template file try

```
{{ race.description.html | safe }}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).