# when I export posts from django I get <django_quill.fields.FieldQuill object at 0x7f0746389840>?

Tags: python, django, quill, django-import-export

I'm working on Django blog and I want to export posts and I made it work but I have a problem when exporting text because I used Quill - rich text editor and Django Import Export

```
body = QuillField()
```

And when I export posts in excel, I got this `<django_quill.fields.FieldQuill object at 0x7f0746389840>`.

excel is looking like this,
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMwih.png)

This is resources.py

```
from import_export import resources
from .models import Post

class PostResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

This is views.py

```
def export_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get selected option from form
        file_format = request.POST['file-format']
        post_resource = PostResource()
        dataset = post_resource.export()
        if file_format == 'CSV':
            response = HttpResponse(dataset.csv, content_type='text/csv')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="exported_data.csv"'
            return response        
        elif file_format == 'JSON':
            response = HttpResponse(dataset.json, content_type='application/json')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="exported_data.json"'
            return response
        elif file_format == 'XLS (Excel)':
            response = HttpResponse(dataset.xls, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="exported_data.xls"'
            return response   

    return render(request, 'dashboard/export.html')
```

Any idea how to get the text in this body column?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems you are exporting the python object and not the text inside

Comment: How can I export text inside?

Comment: You probably need to define more in the PostResource class

Comment: See Import Export Doc https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#advanced-data-manipulation-on-export

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the content from the quill object Post.body.html or Post.body.html

Comment: this works if I use tags in HTML, but how do I use in my case when I'm using export-import and exporting all posts?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```py
from import_export import resources
from import_export.fields import Field
from .models import Post

class PostResource(resources.ModelResource):
    body = Field() 
 
    class Meta:
        model = Post
    
    def dehydrate_body(self,post):
        body_content = post.body.html
    
        return body_content
```

See docs : https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#advanced-data-manipulation-on-export

and [Django Quill Editor Display Saved Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65029744/django-quill-editor-display-saved-field)